# MultiThread on For Loop C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-2.0

I am making a program to check Status of my company servers.
My servers infor will load in DgvServer
I use for loop to check status of servers:

```
    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string ip = "";
            Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
            PingReply pingreplay = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvServer.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //Get IP address
                ip = dgvServer.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                pingreplay = ping.Send(ip,10000);
                if (pingreplay.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    //update status of server
                    dgvServer.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = "Online";
                }
                else
                   //Update status of server
                    dgvServer.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = "Offline";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.show(ex.Message);
            }
    }
```

It's ok if all servers is online, but if some server offline, this code take to long times to finish. So, I want to use one thread for each loop for check status of each server. I don't use parallel because this is .net 2.0 programs.
Please give me some advice to improve this code using thread.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nifty implementation of Parallel.For that works with .NET 2.0

> In this article we will see a way to implement a static For method in C#2.0 having the same behavior.

https://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/how-to-provide-a-parallel-for-loop-in-c2-0-2/

You can use a Parallel.For loop, using the method provided in the article, to poll all of your servers in parallel.

Note that this will still block the UI for as long as the longest single server check takes.

Another option to consider is putting that block of code into a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.80).aspx), so that the UI is not blocked.

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient solution.

You can create one BackgroundWorker per server to update, allowing each server's status to update in the grid as soon as the reply comes in, or you can just create a single BackgroundWorker (which perhaps uses the Parallel.For implementation above).

Answer (score 0):

Try Parallel.For or Parallel.Foreach.

See this link for more information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: He's on .NET 2.0, so this is not available to him through .NET.